# Building creatures with a mist-like atmosphere

Tags: biology, creature-design, xenobiology, weather

What would creatures look like if they evolve on a world that was constantly covered in mist.

Assume the planet is much like Earth, it has 7 continents, various habitat, and a nearby moon, but the only difference is that the entire world is covered in a never ending mist.

Essentially I’m curious about these 2 things:

1. How would a creature evolve  or adapt in said world.
2. What would most plants have in common with each other in said world ( like would they just have regular photosynthesis or something thing else entirely. )

Comment: What you're asking is basically an entire ecosystem being designed. That's a monumental question. You'd probably be better off asking on a smaller scale, i.e. just one animal.

Comment: This is too broad. If there are any particular problems you’d like to focus on (What traits would *not* be advantageous in constant mist would be my suggestion given the answer you already have) then you should reword. Don’t worry about the question being closed whole you’re fixing it though: that’s temporary if you change it enough to make it good again.

Comment: We have mist almost every morning...

Comment: OP asks for tendencies and it quite pointless to narrow considering a planet-wide effect, no one asks and no one capable here to create an entire ecosystem here @Halfthawed How you see it bein narrowed - how plants thrive in such an environment, or instead of all plants - how grass doing well there or instead of all grass - how well lily pads doing there. Narrowing to some particular instance does not do the question better. Answering the question is to consider the main attributes of few kingdoms that's max one can do here. or focusing on light as Aezyc did. Question is 4/10 but it legit

Comment: @MolbOrg Narrowing to a single ecosystem would help, especially a simplistic ecosystem, or asking how a family of animals, i.e. Canidae, might evolve differently. True, such an answer might not be helpful for a world-wide ecosystem, but that doesn't change the fact that asking about a world-wide ecosystem is too broad. I could write a paper dealing with this subject after a month of research, and that would still not even scratch the surface of what we could be dealing with.

Comment: Greetings and welcome!  You might want to check out the [help] and [tour] so you can get a better idea how WB.SE works.  You're asking an interesting question, but it's far too broad to be answered in a forum like this.  Even after the edit, it lacks focus: you might consider honing in on one aspect of native flora or fauna (etc) evolution: like "there is a semi-predatory plantimal-like lifeform that uses the trunks of tall trees in the daily hunting-scavenging migrations as they seek brighter/darker conditions. How might this come about?"

Comment: @Halfthawed there are works which investigate systems of a few types of consuments producents in the whole system - they spend a lot of time and it still not exhausting research/modeling. So it not about how narrow a system is, or which part of it we speak about - but of the question we set to investigate about that system - what specifically we wish to know - it defines the complexity of answer and sure in a full steam complexity there is no bottom for efforts.

Comment: getting to Canidae - it isn't narrowing a question at all - I would doubt any existence of them in such an ecosystem - I mean there is no way for us telling without knowing the whole system. So then, such a "narrowing" is a wrong question to ask at all because it forces us to know the whole complexity, which we can't possibly know at all ever(here). So narrowing is the figuring out some assumed tendencies which may happen in such conditions, leave the author the rest to figure fantasize about.

Comment: @Halfthawed in essence - look at Aezyc answer - it is a good way to approach answering the question. It has a place for improvement but it is good enough. And I would like the see other fundamental changes aspects to pay attention to. Really it is not interesting to read someones opinnion about how Canidae could be (if they can in principle be) in such an environment - those things someone can imagine on its own given one got right direction of thinking, which helps to avoid obivious "won't work in the environment" things

Comment: An analog here on Earth is the ocean: visibility is limited, and photosynthesis only occurs near the top where the sun's rays are still strong. Animals have many different ways to navigate and hunt when sight is insufficient, including chemical (smell), electrical (such as a shark's lateral line), and sonar.

Answer (score 4):

Animals would likely evolve to see in wavelengths unaffected by the mist which would vary based on the composition of said mist. 
I made a world for my art investigation that is covered in atmospheric plankton which turns the planet into an eternal LSD trip with minimal visibility in the visible wavelengths. The animals' eyes and plants' leaves are all white and adapted to using infrared and UV light which isn't absorbed or refracted by the plankton. Filter-feeding, plant-like animals are more plentiful than actual plants though. The plankton also have other effects on the geology and biology of the world, but that's irrelevant to this question.

Mostly, vision and photosythesis, at least in the visible spectrum, will be greatly limited.